# While converting a list consist of string into float throws value error: could not convert string to float: '22.52.58.246'. How to convert into float?

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-conversion

I need to convert the strings from a list into `float` values and append them to a new list.

But I get this error:

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: '22.52.58.246'.

How can I convert them into float?

```py
Time = [
    '22.53.13.106',
    '22.53.13.106',
    '22.53.13.161',
    '22.53.13.161',
    '22.53.13.162'
] 

for i in range(0, len(Time)):
    Time[i] = float(Time[i])
```

Comment: These values do not seem be numeric in literal sense. How do u expect to convert a non numeric value to string

Answer (score 0):

`22.53.13.106` is *not* a valid floating point value<sup>(a)</sup> as it appears to have more than one decimal point. They *could* be IPv4 addresses given no single component is greater than `255`, but you would have to check what's producing them to be sure.

Or, based on the fact that they're called `Time`, they may well be `hh.mm.ss.xxx` (xxx = milliseconds), in which case you need to decide first what units you want them in. For example, floating point hours would be something like:

```py
def hh_mm_ss_MMM_to_hours(arg):
    fields = arg.split(".")
    if len(fields) != 4:
        raise RuntimeError("WTF!")
    ret_val =  int(fields[0])
    ret_val += int(fields[1]) / 60
    ret_val += int(fields[2]) / 60 / 60
    ret_val += int(fields[3]) / 60 / 60 / 1000
    return ret_val

Time=['22.53.13.106', '22.53.13.106', '22.53.13.161', '22.53.13.161', '22.53.13.162']
for time in Time:
    print(f"{time} -> {hh_mm_ss_MMM_to_hours(time)}")
```

That produces:

```
22.53.13.106 -> 22.88697388888889
22.53.13.106 -> 22.88697388888889
22.53.13.161 -> 22.886989166666666
22.53.13.161 -> 22.886989166666666
22.53.13.162 -> 22.886989444444445
```

---

<sup>(a)</sup> Unless you're one of those strange European types who can't seem to figure out the difference between a decimal point and a comma :-)